# Accessing objects from jQ loaded external html without load-callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<script src="support/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" bdHarset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {

    $('body').load('externalFile.html');

    $(window).bind("load", function() {

        $('#targetBtn').click(function() {
            console.log(
                'click function'
            );
        });

    });

});

</script>
```

*#targetBtn is an object in the externalFile.html

The 'click function' does not fire unless I use it inside of callback for the load:

```
$('body').load('externalFile.html', function() {
    $('#targetBtn').click(function() {
        console.log(
            'click function'
        );
    });
});
```

but in my project there're elements that need to reside inside of the $(window).bind for them to work properly which is why I was hoping to essentially have all JS inside of $(window).bind for clarity...

Is there a way to logically resolve this code structure so that it resembles my first example and still have the 'click function' work on objects pulled in from external sources via load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by delegating the event handler:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#targetBtn', function() {
        console.log('click function');
    });

    $('body').load('externalFile.html');
});
```